# If $f(x,y)$ is a polynomial of degree $3$, where $f(a,b)=0$, find $a+b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

$f(x,y)$ is a polynomial of degree $3$ such that

$$f(0,0)=f(\pm 1,0)=f(0, \pm 1)=f(2,2)=0$$, then $f(a,b)=0$ when $a+b=$

$(A)$ $21/20$

$(B)$ $19/21$

$(C)$ $21/19$

$(D)$ $20/21$

If polynomial is of degree 3, can we assume polynomial as $y=ax(x-1)(x+1)$? $f(0,0)=f(\pm 1,0)=0$ or am I missing something?

Comment: $f(x,y)$ a polynomial of two variables, i.e. $f(x,y) = Ax^3 + By^3 + Cxy^2 + \ldots$. What you have written down $y = ax(x-1)(x+1)$ is a polynomial in one variable.

Answer (score 0):

$f$ has the form $$f(x,y) = A \cdot x^3 + B \cdot x^2 y+ C \cdot x y^2+ D \cdot x^2 y+ E \cdot y^3 + F \cdot x^2 + G \cdot xy + H \cdot y^2 + I \cdot x + J \cdot y + K $$

We know $$ 0 = f(0,0) = A \cdot 0 + B \cdot 0 + C \cdot0 + D \cdot 0 + E \cdot 0 + F \cdot 0 + G \cdot 0 + H \cdot 0 + I \cdot 0 + J \cdot 0 + K = K $$

And also $$0 = f(1,0) = A \cdot 1 + B \cdot 0+ C \cdot 0 + D \cdot 0 + E \cdot 0 + F \cdot 1 + G \cdot 0 + H \cdot 0 + I \cdot 1 + J \cdot 0 + 0 = A+F+I $$

You can go on from there.

Comment: You listed the $x^2 y$ term twice. Besides, the polynomial has $10$ coefficients, but only $6$ constraints are given, so it's not obvious where you go from there.